# Retrieving user_location from the access_token returns empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully generated `access_token` for my website. I am able to retrieve all the required information, except one i.e., `user_location`. I tried to use the following two methods to retrieve location , but both return empty string.

**Method-1**

```
string access_tokens = tokens["access_token"];

var client = new FacebookClient(access_tokens);

dynamic me = client.Get("me");

string user_location me["user_location"].ToString();
```

**Method-2**

```
string user_location = GetUserLocation(fb_id);

//and here is the method

 public static string GetUserLocation(string faceBookId)
            {
                WebResponse response = null;
                string user_location = string.Empty;
                try
                {
                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/user_location", faceBookId));
                    response = request.GetResponse();
                    user_location = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //catch exception
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (response != null) response.Close();
                }
                return user_location;
            }
```

Location is actually received when I try to debug in the Graph API Explorer at developer.facebook.com ! When I put the parameter **`location`** - the location is received as expected.

Alternately I also tried to change the request URL with this :

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/location", faceBookId));
```

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `/user-ID/user_location` edge in Facebook's Graph API.

There is a [`location` field](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading) on the `/user-ID` object.

`user_location` is the name of the OAuth permission scope that you need to obtain in order to be able to read that field. See also: [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-user_location).

Comment: `string user_location = me["user_location"].ToString();` doing this gives me a KeyNotFoundException... As when I tried to retrieve the location in the GRAPH Api.. an array is returned with `ID` and `location`

Comment: URI: `https://graph.facebook.com/<version>/<user ID>?fields=location&access_token=<token>`. You can read about the difference between objects, fields and edges [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api).

Comment: `WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/fields=location&access_token={1}", faceBookId,access_token));` .. I wrote this request, but this returns empty string :O

Comment: I hope the UserID and the FacebookID is the same  ?

Comment: This is how i have mentioned the scope parameters : `string scope = "public_profile,user_location";`